# Graal.js importing module causes org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Expected an operand but found import

Tags: java, jsr223, graalvm, graaljs

I am trying to use experimental ES module support from Grall.js.
I use following scripts: ES module "lib"

```
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
```

and main script "script"

```
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log('square(11)=' + square(11));
console.log('diag(4,3)=' + diag(4, 3));
```

I use graalvm-ce-19.2.1 and I use Polyglot inside JVM via [JSR 223](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/JavaInterop.md#scriptengine-jsr-223) to run the main script. 
Instead of trying to load lib from some place on disk it throws:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: script:1:0 Expected an operand but found import
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
^
script:1:30 Expected ; but found lib
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
                              ^
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:348)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:323)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a convention on file names which trigger treating them as ES modules - file must end with `.mjs`. Alternatively it is possible to use (unofficial) mime type `application/javascript+module` on `org.graalvm.polyglot.Source` object. Without this `import` statement is not allowed [1](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/92#issuecomment-474858574).

This is how it looks when using Polyglot Source/Context API:

```
String script = "import {x} from 'lib'";

// these two support "import"
Source source1 =  Source.newBuilder("js", script, "script.mjs").build();
Source source2 =  Source.newBuilder("js", script, "script").mimeType("application/javascript+module").build();

// this one doesn't
//Source source3 =  Source.newBuilder("js", script, "script").build();
```

and this is for JSR-223 API:

```
javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("graal.js");
engine.getContext().setAttribute(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, "script.mjs", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
```

It seems that there also was [an older convention](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/graal-dev/2017-August/005050.html) - using `module:` prefix, but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Where is the official documentation for this?

Comment: As far as I remember there is only this comment: https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/92#issuecomment-474858574

Comment: Oh it seems there is some new piece of documentation here https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NodeJSVSJavaScriptContext.md#ecmascript-modules-ecm